# Does the Spark driver wait for all partitions to finish work from rdd.foreachPartition before continuing?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

For example, if I have the following code running in the Spark driver:

```
rdd.foreachPartition(iterator => myFunc(iterator))

val x = 1
```

Will the driver wait for each partition to finish running `myFunc()` before moving on and setting the variable `x`? Or will the driver set `x` while at least one partition is still running `myFunc()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does. All `RDD` methods, with exception to [`AsyncRDDActions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.AsyncRDDActions) are blocking, and wait until related tasks complete.